# How to extend lines in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I wrote an animator class that would accept multiple lines' y coords, which I want to extend dynamically according to fresh data.

The problem is, even though I specified the line labels it doesn't seem to treat my lines as one instance. Instead, it treats them as new lines.

Therefore I get new line colors and legends every single time:

[image]

Is there any way to fix this behavior, aside from creating an internal database of colors within the class and reusing them according to line index?

But still I don't really like that it treats my lines as new instances every single time and I wonder if there is maybe a simple fix for this behavior.

```
import time
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class Animator:
    def __init__(self):
        plt.ion()
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.x = 0
        self.Y = np.array([],dtype='object')
        
    def add(self, Y):
        if (self.Y.size == 0 ):
            self.Y = Y
        for i, y in enumerate(Y):
            plt.plot([self.x,self.x+1], [self.Y[i],y], label=f'line{i+1}')
        plt.legend()
        self.x+=1
        self.Y=Y
        self.fig.canvas.flush_events()
        
animator = Animator()   

y_vals = np.random.normal(scale=3,size=(10,3)).cumsum(axis=0)
for i in range(len(y_vals)):
    animator.add(y_vals[i])
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I'm not sure but shouldn't you call `self.fig.canvas.draw()` before flushing?

Comment: I used **ion()** mode in the init.

Comment: Alright, is your indenting correct to update the values in the loop?

Comment: Yes, using a different kind of loop that performs a lot of calculations and then spits outs the metric at the end of each cycle. Sometimes it can take a while so I need to see a live data.

Comment: Well, the solution is, as you imagined: *"creating an internal database of colors within the class and reusing them according to line index"*.  Why do you think that isn't a good idea?

Comment: Because they are instances of a single line (well 3 in this case). It just feels kind of wrong conceptually.

Comment: Last question, any reason you're not using the dedicated matplotlib way to do this ? https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html

Comment: I don't know if using that would actually solve my problem. From what I've gathered using blit can improve performance but this isn't an issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it isn't as bad after all... what do you think?

```
class Animator:
    def __init__(self, style=('b-', 'm--', 'g-.', 'r:')):
        plt.ion()
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.x = 0
        self.Y = np.array([],dtype='object')
        self.fmts=lambda a: style[a%len(style)]
        
    def add(self, Y):
        if (self.Y.size == 0 ):
            self.Y = Y
        for i, y in enumerate(Y):
            plt.plot([self.x,self.x+1], [self.Y[i],y], self.fmts(i), label=f'line{i+1}')
        if (self.x==0):
            plt.legend(loc='upper left')
        self.x+=1
        self.Y=Y
        self.fig.canvas.flush_events()
```